# Implementing an Iterative Single Stack Binary Tree Copy Function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As a thought exercise I am trying to implement an iterative tree (binary or binary search tree) copy function.

It is my understanding that it can be achieved trivially:

- with a single stack
- without using a wrapper (that contains references to the copy and original nodes)
- without a node having a reference to it's parent (would a parent reference in a node be counter to a true definition of a tree [which I believe is a DAG]?)

I have written different implementations that meet the inverse of the above constraints but I am uncertain how to approach the problem with the constraints.

I did not see anything in Algorithms 4/e and have not seen anything online (beyond statements of how trivial it is). I considered using the concepts from in order and post order of a current/previous var but I did not see a way to track accurately when popping the stack. I also briefly considered a hash map but I feel this is still just extra storage like the extra stack.

Any help in understanding the concepts/idioms behind the approach that I am not seeing is gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Some requests for what I've tried so far. Here is the 2 stack solution which I believe is supposed to be able to turn into the 1 stack the most trivially.

It's written in C++. I am new to the language (but not programming) and teaching myself using C++ Primer 5/e (Lippman, Lajole, Moo) [C++11] and the internet. If any of the code from a language perspective is wrong, please let me know (although I'm aware Code Review Stack Exchange is the place for an actual review).

I have a template Node that is used by other parts of the code.

```
template<typename T>
struct Node;

typedef Node<std::string> tree_node;
typedef std::shared_ptr<tree_node> shared_ptr_node;

template<typename T>
struct Node final {

public:
    const T value;
    const shared_ptr_node &left = m_left;
    const shared_ptr_node &right = m_right;

    Node(const T value, const shared_ptr_node left = nullptr, const shared_ptr_node right = nullptr) : value(value), m_left(left), m_right (right) {}

    void updateLeft(const shared_ptr_node node) {
        m_left = node;
    }

    void updateRight(const shared_ptr_node node) {
        m_right = node;
    }

private:
    shared_ptr_node m_left;
    shared_ptr_node m_right;
};
```

And then the 2 stack implementation.

```
shared_ptr_node iterativeCopy2Stacks(const shared_ptr_node &node) {

    const shared_ptr_node newRoot = std::make_shared<tree_node>(node->value);

    std::stack<const shared_ptr_node> s;
    s.push(node);

    std::stack<const shared_ptr_node> copyS;
    copyS.push(newRoot);

    shared_ptr_node original = nullptr;
    shared_ptr_node copy = nullptr;

    while (!s.empty()) {

        original = s.top();
        s.pop();

        copy = copyS.top();
        copyS.pop();

        if (original->right) {
            s.push(original->right);

            copy->updateRight(std::make_shared<tree_node>(original->right->value));
            copyS.push(copy->right);
        }

        if (original->left) {
            s.push(original->left);

            copy->updateLeft(std::make_shared<tree_node>(original->left->value));
            copyS.push(copy->left);
        }
    }

    return newRoot;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: Do you have a recursive version of the copy function? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: What does a "wrapper" mean exactly in the second condition?

Comment: And what kind of information are we allowed to store in the stack?

Comment: Note that a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is not a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). To say "tree (B or BST)" is ... kind of wonky. Did you mean "binary tree or binary search tree?"

Comment: @JimMischel, thank you for pointing that out. Yes, "binary tree or binary search tree?" is what I meant, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @ThomasRollet I've added the two stack solution and I've linked in my comment to kraskevich a post which informed some of my other successful attempts.

Comment: @kraskevich In my experiments that stack holds shared pointers to Nodes string values. I've posted my code for the 2 stack version. Much of what informed my attempts came out of an old SO post: stackoverflow.com/questions/9647559/… In this, the user uses a wrapper object to hold a pointer to both the original and the copy. The accepted solution is to use a node with a reference back to the parent, but I feel that this solution doesn't work for me and what I want to learn. – GoodEgg 7 hours ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fluent in c++, so you'll have to settle with pseudocode:

```
node copy(treenode n):
    if n == null
        return null

    node tmp = clone(n) //no deep clone!!!

    stack s
    s.push(tmp)

    while !s.empty():
        node n = s.pop()

        if n.left != null:
            n.left = clone(n.left)
            s.push(n.left)
        if n.right != null:
            n.right = clone(n.right)
            s.push(n.right)

    return tmp
```

Note that `clone(node)` is **not** a deep-clone. The basic idea is to start with a shallow-clone of the root, then iterate over all children of that node and replace those nodes (still references to the original node) by shallow copies, replace those nodes children, etc.. This algorithm traverses the tree in a DFS-manner. In case you prefer BFS (for whatever reason) you could just replace the stack by a queue. Another advantage of this code: it can be altered with a few minor changes to work for arbitrary trees.

A recursive version of this algorithm (in case you prefer recursive code over my horrible prosa):

```
node copyRec(node n):
    if n.left != null:
        n.left = clone(n.left)
        copyRec(n.left)

    if n.right != null:
        n.right = clone(n.right)
        copyRec(n.right)

    return n

node copy(node n):
    return copyRec(clone(n))
```

EDIT:
If you want to have a look at working code, I've created an [implementation](https://github.com/BabitsPaul/pythonplayground/blob/master/bst.py) in python.

Comment: thank you for the shallow copy idea and thank you for the extra step of the pseudo code and real code.

Comment: @GoodEgg glad to help ;). Since you're new here: if this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you. I had a couple of replies to my initial question so I'm going to wait a short while to accept the answer - but given the restrictions around data structures I believe your suggested approach is correct.